# how to configure nginx and cakephp 2.x for customized error page (404, 500, ...)?

Tags: nginx, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.3

Good Morning,
  using cakephp 2.x along with nginx, does anyone know how I can customize the error pages, such 404, 500 etc..
  How to configure nginx both, as the cake.
  I searched but only found how to do using apache.
Any questions can be answered already, or tutorial.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You would use the [`error_page`](http://nginx.org/r/error_page) directive to the configure customised error pages in nginx.

Comment: what I can not do, is the necessary settings in nginx and cake2.3 to direct the errors to custom error pages.

Comment: You should use `error_page` together with [`fastcgi_intercept_errors`](http://nginx.org/r/fastcgi_intercept_errors), or another `_intercept_errors` directive if using an upstream other than `fastcgi_`.